# Using boxes (from \savebox) across beamer frames

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm trying to use `\usebox` on different frames but it doesn't work as (I) expected. On the following example, I expected the second slide also containing one second ellipse.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\MyBox}
\begin{frame}
    \savebox{\MyBox}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) ellipse (1cm and 2cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \usebox{\MyBox}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \usebox{\MyBox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

PS: The reason I'm trying to do this is to create a thumbnail of a picture so that when you you click you jump to the slide containing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By moving the tikzpicture (and its `\savebox`) outside of the `framed` environment, its influence can extend over the document.  By placing it in the environment (as you had originally done), you limit the reach of the picture to that environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\MyBox}
    \savebox{\MyBox}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) ellipse (1cm and 2cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
\begin{frame}
    \usebox{\MyBox}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \usebox{\MyBox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

`\savebox` makes a *local* assignment to the box register. Thus the setting is lost after the end of the current environment `frame`. This can be changed by a global `\setbox` assignment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\MakeGlobalBox}[1]{%
  \global\setbox#1=\copy#1\relax
}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\MyBox}
\begin{frame}
    \savebox{\MyBox}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) ellipse (1cm and 2cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    \usebox{\MyBox}
    \MakeGlobalBox\MyBox
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \usebox{\MyBox}       
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- BTW, I have removed the spaces at the left and right side of the box contents. They were caused by line ends after `\savebox{\MyBox}{` and after `\end{tikzpicture}`.